# Key union from fields of mixed object array

Tags: typescript

I have an array for fields containing different fields to be shown in UI.

```
const fields = [
  {
    id: 'textInput_1',
    fieldType: 'text',
  },
  {
    id: 'selectInput_1',
    fieldType: 'select',
  },
  {
    id: 'textInput_2',
    fieldType: 'text',
  },
] as const;
```

For my text and select input handlers, I want them to accept key whose type is union of values of `id` fields where `fieldType` is `'text'` and `'select'` respectively.

I'm able to get a union of all keys like this

```
type ArrayElement<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]> = ArrayType extends readonly (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never;

type ItemKeys = ArrayElement<typeof fields>['id']; // 'textInput_1' | 'selectInput_1' | 'textInput_2'
```

What I get to wish is the following types dynamically

```
type TextItemKeys = 'textInput_1' | 'textInput_2';
type SelectItemKeys = 'selectInput_1';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to get the type of a field is to index with a number `typeof field[number]`

You can the use the predefined `Extract` type to get only those constituents of the union that have a particular `fieldType`:

```
type ItemType  = typeof fields[number];

type TextItemKeys = Extract<ItemType, { fieldType: 'text'}>['id'];
type SelectItemKeys = Extract<ItemType, { fieldType: 'select'}>['id'];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwKYBsAmEYF4YG0BQMMA3oUTAmgFwwDkUSAHlAJJgAOArlAPoCMtADRkiiVGgAqAT3ZIa9JlCFkAvsKKlyFanQiokwVh279lWsemmz5elAaXqYaspvKV5DZmy68ATGfILSRk5Ok8HVWEAXRgAQ0xQSCgAbnx8KBCYFgYAWyskIhwM2RA4eGR0CFwwThyAIyQAJyjU9MyJRWykHIBpJClMHABRZkbYwwAeLryQwRJy8XyPRVoVAD5cWkpaFrbZGABlfUNpvoHsGBGoMcnp-LniBcsQm2Oldc3tlqA)